# WLST - JVM arguments dump for every server nodes

Tags: java, jvm, weblogic, wlst

I need to get the JVM startup arguments of a concrete WebLogic node, using WLST. Admin console: `Environment -> Server tab -> Arguments`

I can access the default one trought mbean `java.lang:type=Runtime` and it's attribute `InputArguments` :

```
objectName=ObjectName("java.lang:type=Runtime")
attrs=mbs.getAttribute(objectName,"InputArguments")
for attr in attrs:
print attr
```

But I need to access and display it for every server node in my domain, because they have different JVM attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're almost there. Here's the WLST way to do it, assuming you are connected to the admin server:

```
for i in ls('/Servers', returnMap='true'):
    cd('/Servers/'+i+'/ServerStart/'+i)
    print(cmo.getArguments())
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my final version:

```
for i in ls('/Servers', returnMap='true'):
    domainCustom()
    cd ('java.lang')
    cd('java.lang:Location='+i+',type=Runtime')
    print(ls())
```